# Cases for x in $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (xy^2 \neq y - x) $.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

This is from Velleman p145, problem 28.

Theorem: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (xy^2 \neq y - x)$.

---

Author's Proof:

Let x be an arbitrary real number.

Case 1. $x = 0$. Let $y = 1$. Then $xy^2 = 0$ and y - x = 1 = 1 = 0 = 1, so $xy^2 \neq y - x$.

Case 2. $x \neq 0$. Let $y = 0$. Then $xy^2 = 0$ and $y - x = -x \neq 0$, so $xy^2 \neq y - x$.

Since these cases are exhaustive, we have shown that $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}(xy^2 \neq y - x)$. Since x was arbitrary, this shows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(xy^2 \neq y - x)$.

---

My proof:

Let x be an arbitrary real number. Let y = 0. Then $xy^2 = 0$ and $y - x = -x \neq 0$, so $xy^2 \neq y - x$. Since x was arbitrary, this shows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(xy^2 \neq y - x)$.

---

Can someone explain why the author used cases in his proof? I see the $\forall x$, so we do a "let x be arbitrary...". Then we have a $\exists y$, so we just need to prove one possible existence. That should be enough, as far as I can tell.

The author's use of cases implies some disjunction in the givens and I simply don't see it. Where is the disjunction?

Comment: If your arbitrary real number $x$ is $0$, then your choice of $y=0$ doesn't work.

Comment: $\forall x \varphi(x)$ and $\forall x \neq 0 \varphi(x) \wedge \varphi(0)$ mean the same when the universe of discourse is $\mathbb{R}$.  That is because an *arbitrary* real number is either zero, or not; in other words, $\{0\}\cup \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x\neq 0\}=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your proof with $x = 0$:

Let $x = 0$ (this is OK, $x$ is an arbitrary real). Let $y = 0$. Then $xy^2 = 0 \cdot 0^2 = 0$ and $ y - x = 0 - x = -x = 0 $. You've said that $-x \neq 0$, but as we can see, that doesn't hold when $x=0$.